# How could we add multiple user in a single Definer for a MYSQL databases object like procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, procedure

please suggest : for  MYSQL databases object like procedure there is already a definer user . i required to add another user in to it so that both user can access and execute same procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to have multiple users as DEFINER for MySQL Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511862/possible-to-have-multiple-users-as-definer-for-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: You don't need to add another definer - you need to `grant execute on procedure mydb.myprod to bill;`. The link above is all the detail you need.

Comment: Not if your procedures have parameters and you're using a graphical tool that like phpMyAdmin or Adminer, that should shot input fields for those